# Send cookies over HTTPURLConnection

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, response

I am trying use the HTTPURLConnection class to open connection to a JSP and receive a response from a servlet. A response header is set in the JSP that need to be read in the servlet.

The code sample is as below

```
String strURL = "http://<host>:<port>/<context>/mypage.jsp";
String sCookies = getCookie();//method to get the authentication cookie(**SSOAUTH**) and its value for the current logged in user

URL url = new URL(strURL);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", URLEncoder.encode(sCookies, "UTF-8"));
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("lang=en");
out.flush();
out.close();

 //reading the response received from JSP and retrieve header value
response.write(urlConnection.getHeaderField("commAuth") + "<br />");
```

The issue is the passed **SSOAUTH** cookie is not sent to the JSP. If I send the UID/PWD instead of cookie as below the authentication succeeds and response is sent correctly.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("username", "testuser");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("password", "testpwd");
```

Is this the right way of sending cookie over HTTPURLConnection? or are there other parameters that need to be set?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try removing the URLEncoder.encode from the entire sCookies String. The cookie format should be in the form of NAME=VALUE, but by URLEncoding the whole string you will escape the =.

Comment: I removed the Encoding and modified it as      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", URLEncoder.encode(sCookies, "UTF-8"));  but this does not makes any difference.

Comment: I was thinking of: urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookies); since urlencoding JSESSIONID=SOMETHING will transform it to JSESSIONID%3DSOMETHING and may not be valid. Also, when you say it is not working, is nothing being sent or is the cookie just not being set correctly? Can you see if any Set-Cookie headers are being sent (either by debugging on the server or taking a look at the traffic through something like wireshark)?